# When access to directmessage in twitter4j, an error shows "unable to parse '3577866941' as integer"

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have set the value of ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESSTOKEN_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET which I got from dev.twitter but it crashes when the application runs.I use twitter4j-core-2.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar as library.The code is given bellow.

```
public ResponseList<DirectMessage> dmList=null;
public static AccessToken token = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESSTOKEN_SECRET);
TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory();
twitter = factory.getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(token); 
try {
    dmList = twitter.getDirectMessages(new Paging(1,15));
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter userID and tweetID are not 32 bit integers. They recently upgraded them to 64bit, maybe your library is out of date ?